# sort table by column but taking into account hidden rows associated to each row

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a table which I want to sort by columns when clicking on the column header, however the table also has rows which are hidden that are assigned to each row. The problem is if I sort the table by column it will also sort those hidden rows and they will lose the association with their rows. Eg. the `<tr class="grey">` rows are always visible and each one has hidden rows such as `<tr class="sales-details-title hide">` and `<tr class="sales-details hide">`

```
  <table width="100%" class="modal-table" id="modal-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="sn">Surgeon name</th>
                <th id="ct">Country</th>
                <th>Antiquity</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>dfvdf dscdsc</td>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>new client</td>
                <td>10000.0 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Support</td>
                <td>10000.0 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>Alexander Larrazabal</td>
                <td>Spain</td>
                <td>renewal</td>
                <td>9423.0 EUR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>larra support</td>
                <td>9423.0 EUR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>fadadfs sdfdsf</td>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>new client</td>
                <td>901.55 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Fabri</td>
                <td>901.55 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>such surgeon</td>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>new client</td>
                <td>901.55 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Fabri</td>
                <td>901.55 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>Alexander Larrazabal</td>
                <td>Spain</td>
                <td>renewal</td>
                <td>9423.0 EUR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>larra support</td>
                <td>9423.0 EUR</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

JQUERY:

```
function sortTable(f,n){
  var rows = $('#modal-table tbody  tr').get();

  rows.sort(function(a, b) {

    var A = getVal(a);
    var B = getVal(b);

    if(A < B) {
      return -1*f;
    }
    if(A > B) {
      return 1*f;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  function getVal(elm){
    var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
    if($.isNumeric(v)){
      v = parseInt(v,10);
    }
    return v;
  }

  $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
    $('#modal-table').children('tbody').append(row);
  });
}

var f_sn = 1;
var f_ct = 1;

$(document).on("click ", "#modal-table th", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  if(id == 'sn')
   f_sn *= -1;
  if(id == 'ct')
   f_ct *= -1;

  var n = $(this).prevAll().length;

  if(id == 'sn')
   sortTable(f_sn,n);
  if(id == 'ct')
   sortTable(f_ct,n);

});
```

Comment: Why not to use a tbody for each row pair? It will be more correct from the semantic point of view and your job will be much more easier because, then, you only will need to sort those tbodys.

Comment: @user1937021, Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @bitifet suggestion in the comment - here is a code that will sort your table by `tbody` (each related rows are grouped inside a new `tbody` tag).

The sort is done by the first `tr` that has the `grey` class.
I also added some css so you can view (opacity of 0.5) the hidden rows.

If you don't want/can't change the html structure I also added a `prepareTableForSorting` function that will make sure the table's structure is the one you need to handle the sorting.

```js
function sortTable(f,n){
  var rowsGroups = $('#modal-table tbody').get();

  rowsGroups.sort(function(a, b) {

    var A = getVal($(a).find('tr.grey'));
    var B = getVal($(b).find('tr.grey'));

    if(A < B) {
      return -1*f;
    }
    if(A > B) {
      return 1*f;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  function getVal(elm){
    var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(n).text().toUpperCase();
    if($.isNumeric(v)){
      v = parseInt(v,10);
    }
    return v;
  }

  $.each(rowsGroups, function(index, grp) {
    $('#modal-table').append(grp);
  });
}

var f_sn = 1;
var f_ct = 1;

function prepareTableForSorting(tblId) {
  var chunk = $()
  $('#' + tblId).find('tr.grey').each(function() {
    var chunk = $(this)
    $(this).nextAll('tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('grey')) {
        return false
      }
      chunk = chunk.add(this)
    });
    if (chunk) {
      $('#modal-table').append($('<tbody>').append(chunk))
    }
  });
}

prepareTableForSorting('modal-table');

$(document).on("click ", "#modal-table th", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  if(id == 'sn')
   f_sn *= -1;
  if(id == 'ct')
   f_ct *= -1;

  var n = $(this).prevAll().length;

  if(id == 'sn')
   sortTable(f_sn,n);
  if(id == 'ct')
   sortTable(f_ct,n);

});
```

```css
.grey {
  background: grey;
}
.hide {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" class="modal-table" id="modal-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th id="sn">Surgeon name</th>
                <th id="ct">Country</th>
                <th>Antiquity</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>dfvdf dscdsc</td>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>new client</td>
                <td>10000.0 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Support</td>
                <td>10000.0 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>Alexander Larrazabal</td>
                <td>Spain</td>
                <td>renewal</td>
                <td>9423.0 EUR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>larra support</td>
                <td>9423.0 EUR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>fadadfs sdfdsf</td>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>new client</td>
                <td>901.55 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Fabri</td>
                <td>901.55 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>such surgeon</td>
                <td>United States</td>
                <td>new client</td>
                <td>901.55 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Fabri</td>
                <td>901.55 USD</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="grey">
                <td>Alexander Larrazabal</td>
                <td>Spain</td>
                <td>renewal</td>
                <td>9423.0 EUR</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details-title hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><strong>Seller</strong>
                </td>
                <td><strong>Percentage</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="sales-details hide">
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>larra support</td>
                <td>9423.0 EUR</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Hope it helps.